# Model for replacement

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

If $R_{k} $ is a model for replacement, is necesarly k a strong limit cardinal?

And if k is a regular cardinal, are then equivalent the sentences:

k is a strongly inaccesible cardinal if and only if $ ZFC ^  {R_{K}}  $   ? is an equivalence, or only one way of the biconditional is valid?

Comment: Please use standard terminology. The term "strong cardinal" has a very specific meaning. Perhaps you mean **strong limit** instead?

Comment: Yes, it´s strong limit cardinal. I´m sorry for the terminology, what happens is that in Mexico we name that as "fuertes" (inaccesible only, and not as strong limit cardinal)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $R_\kappa$ is a model of the axiom of replacement as well the axiom of choice, then every set has an injection into the ordinals of $R_\kappa$, which is exactly $\kappa$. In particular, if $x\in R_\kappa$, $|\mathcal P(x)|\leq\kappa$.

This immediately tells us that $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal (and in fact that $\kappa=\beth_\kappa$). And strong limit cardinals are strongly inaccessible if and only if they are regular.

However it is not necessary, in general, that $\kappa$ is regular. Indeed, if such $\kappa$ exists that $R_\kappa$ is a model of replacement (and therefore of $\sf ZFC$), then the least such $\kappa$ is singular.

So the equivalence, in general, is false. But if one requires that $\kappa$ is regular it holds.